# How can I revert a package to a specific version on Gentoo?

Tags: package-management, gentoo, version

I'm a Debian user pretty much new to Gentoo. I wanted to install a specific version of a package namely the 1.39.0 version of dev-libs/boost, http://packages.gentoo.org/package/dev-libs/boost. But I already did "emerge dev-libs/boost" which installed me version 1.46.1-r1.

```
machine ~ # emerge --search boost
(...)
*  dev-libs/boost
      Latest version available: 1.46.1-r1
      Latest version installed: 1.46.1-r1
      Size of files: 41,016 kB
      Homepage:      http://www.boost.org/
      Description:   Boost Libraries for C++
      License:       Boost-1.0
```

How can I revert this package back to version 1.39.0?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boost packages are slotted, so you can actually have more than one version installed.

To emerge that version, simply issue:

```
emerge -a =dev-libs/boost-1.39.0
```

If you want to remove the newer version (quite dangerous, you could have a lot of stuff dependent on it), you could:

```
emerge --unmerge =dev-libs/boost-1.46.1-r1
```

and run a `revdep-rebuild` afterwards.

To switch your environment from one version to the other (if you kept both), use `eselect boost list/set`.

Comment: Wow, thank you! It did it. You're God, and doubt anyone that says otherwise! :)